# Rotate For a Max - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, rotation

Trying to solve this [Codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/rotate-for-a-max/train/javascript).

Given a number, we are keeping track of the different (left) rotation results and returning the greatest result.

However, this rotate is different from a typical rotate - because `n` number of digits will stay static after being rotated, and `n` increases with each rotate.

So for example, given the number `56789`, we'll have:

> `67895` (6 stays in place, 7 gets rotated to the back)
>
> `68957` (6 and 8 stay in place, 9 gets rotated to the back)
>
> `68579` (6, 8, and 5 stay in place, 7 gets rotated to the back)
>
> `68597` (6, 8, 5, and 9 stay in place - no more rotations can occur)

Then return the max from these values - `68957`.

I have the following code:

```js
function maxRot(n) {
  let listOfNums = [];
  let array = Array.from(n.toString());
  let num = 0;
  while (num < array.length -1) {
    let number = array.splice(num, 1);
    array.push(Number(number));
    listOfNums.push(Number(array.join("")));
    num++;
  }
  listOfNums.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return listOfNums[0];
}
console.log(maxRot(56789));
```

But it is failing close to half of the tests on Codewars.

And as you can see, my logic is to splice a number each time and append it to the end of the array, then push the updated array into a `listOfNums` array, and then sort that array from greatest to least and return the first value.

Not sure what else to try.

Again, [here's the link to the challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/rotate-for-a-max/train/javascript).

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the original number to the list.

Comment: @georg Yep, that did it.

Comment: There is just one decision at each step: Rotate or not? When the bigger digit gets rotated to the front, then the resulting number is bigger. Therefore you just need to iterate once, and generate one number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @georg pointed out, I forgot to add the original number back into the list.

```
function maxRot(n) {
  let listOfNums = [];
  let array = Array.from(n.toString());
  let num = 0;
  while (num < array.length -1) {
    let number = array.splice(num, 1);
    array.push(Number(number));
    listOfNums.push(Number(array.join("")));
    num++;
  }
  listOfNums.unshift(n);
  listOfNums.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return listOfNums[0];
}
```